# Searching for question having strictly a certain set of tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

Is there a way to search for question which contains a specific tag (or set of tag), but no other tags.

For example if I wanted to have only pure [php] questions I would input in the search filed the following:

`![php]`

Or for question only concerning html and css I would input:

`![html+css]`

Is there already such a feature hidden in the SO Engine? If not, with the high number of question in SO, I feel like it would be a good feature.

Comment: Can you give an example where this would be useful? There could be any number of secondary tags on a question, but that doesn't make it any less relevant to a tag search. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You'd have to get people to tag "pure php" questions with *only* the php tag first.

Comment: @CodeNaked: That is an idea which came to me when browsing the unanswered question to see if I can find something I could answer. But more often than not, the question are about the subject I know, plus a tool I am not familiar with, or a combination of languages which are individually familiar, however never encountered together. And browsing through the 300.000+ unanswered question can take a long time.

Comment: @Bill I'm sure there are question which have only one tag, there must be.

Comment: There's not too many [unanswered, open questions only tagged with `php`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112069/). There are quite a few [single tag, open questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112070/), though.

Comment: A single tag can sometimes be an indicator of low quality, so that kind of search might be useful for pruning purposes.

Comment: @Tim: `php` was just an example to illustrate my idea.

Comment: Your use of "!" would be confusing to some of us, as it often means "not" as in I might read your "![php]" as "all tagged items that are *not* tagged with "[php]."

Comment: @John: I admit that it might be confusing, any suggestion as what other symbol could be used in this case?

Comment: @Tim Stone: I made a few change to your query, to search for the [Number of unanswered post with single tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1841/number-of-unanswered-post-with-single-tag-sorted-by-tag). This and Brock Adams helped me find a few answers where I could at least try to help.

Comment: I would like to hear the opinion of the person who downvoted this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not find any single symbolic way in common use to specify a search *only* for one particular tag and excluding all others.  As mentioned in my earlier comment, I do *not* approve your recommendation of '!' because it too closely resembles the negation operator used in many modern computer programming languages.

My best guess at a reasonable design is to use the asterisk, '*' to emphasize "only."

> Example: type '*[php]' to specify "give me *only* items tagged with 'php' and nothing else."

This would avoid implying something like the "not" operator in common use.

I would also recommend providing '+' to make a tag required and '-' to prohibit one, including the ability to use multiple plusses and multiple minuses.

> Example: '+[php] +[css] -[PDF]' to specify "give me items tagged with
>   '[php]' and '[css]' but not with '[PDF]'.

That syntax is used at [Delicious](http://www.delicious.com/) and in Google searches, so it is reasonably intuitive.

Comment: Asterisk in turn might seem similar to wildcard or some kind of fuzzy search or regex/shell-pattern.

Answer (score 3):

See my answer to ["Search for undertagged questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105617/search-for-undertagged-questions/105618#105618).

You can do this with the Data Explorer if you don't mind data that lags by a month.

[Here's a search for questions with only the php tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1839/undertagged-question-finder?DesiredTags=%3Cphp%3E).

[Likewise for only html+css](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1839/undertagged-question-finder?DesiredTags=%3Chtml%3E%3Ccss%3E).

Comment: I've found a way to look for questions [without](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105548/searching-for-question-having-strictly-a-certain-set-of-tag/113033#113033) the one month tag.

Answer (score 2):

I've just noticed that if you do

```
[php] closed:0
```

and you sort by relevance, it looks like the first 5000 hits are only tagged with [php](/questions/tagged/php) and nothing else.

If you're doing the query to tag under-tagged questions, this has the advantage over Brock's answer of not having the one-month lag.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to search only for questions about php, but not about frameworks, then do something like

```
[php] -[zend-framework] -[codeigniter]
```

That way, you could search for questions that are about pure php, but also happen to mention, say, [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays).