# Search for undertagged questions

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching for question having strictly a certain set of tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105548/searching-for-question-having-strictly-a-certain-set-of-tag)

How do I search for undertagged questions? For example, [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) questions that don't have any other tags associated with it.

Comment: @Tim Stone: Interesting coincidence, considering it was only asked 10 hours ago! I think mine's the better question though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind data that's about a month old, you can do this with the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=recent).

[Here's a query that does that](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1839/undertagged-question-finder).

[Here are the results for just the ruby tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1839/undertagged-question-finder?DesiredTags=%3Cruby%3E).

~~~  
Note that for multiple tags, order is not guaranteed!

For example:

```
<ruby><ruby-on-rails>
```

returns different hits than:

```
<ruby-on-rails><ruby>
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this! The main disadvantage of data that's a month old is that if you're cleaning up, the cleaned up questions still remain there.