# Exclusive tag filtering

Tags: feature-request, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching for question having strictly a certain set of tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105548/searching-for-question-having-strictly-a-certain-set-of-tag)

Would be nice to be able to get a list of questions that are **only** tagged with selected tag (e.g. if I'm asking for C# - don't give me a list of questions tagged with C# *and* Sharepoint).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+-sharepoint solves your example case, but I'm not sure what good it would be to search for questions with no tag other than c#

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/ covers searching with and/or/not

Comment: Say I want to see questions that are specifically about language features of C#; I don't want Sharepoint, EF, etc mixed in.

Comment: Also, I think a lot of questions are overtagged. You see a question about EF that has C#, .NET, EF, and maybe database tags. Well, it probably is a strictly EF question - language doesn't really matter (as long as it's .NET, which is implied); same with database.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for *only* a specific tag is probably never useful, except to do tag-cleanups by finding improperly tagged questions (few questions should have only a single tag).

But you can already *exclude* tags from your search quite easily.  If you want questions related to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) but not [sharepoint](/questions/tagged/sharepoint), simply search for:

```
[C#] -[sharepoint]
```

Comment: That's not quite it, but it gets there. Thanks for the hint!