# Give the possibility to filter questions that are using only given tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, filtering

Is would be very useful to filter the questions that are using **only** given tag. In other words, questions, that have only one tag, and this is the particular tag.

For example: questions tagged only with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

Could it be something like `[javascript]*` ?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do it with SE's search, but it's totally possible using Data.SE.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thank you, I haven't found it - but I wasn't using the word 'singleton'. Now when I know there's nothing like that, I want to have it :)

Comment: Here's another related one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105548/searching-for-question-having-strictly-a-certain-set-of-tag